# Reactjs Hooks Context Provider with no token present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I have a reactjs context which checks the localstorage token and then passes data down from it to the other componenets. However if a user tries to load a page without having access I want it to navigate back to the login component. However I keep getting this error "{message: 'Invalid token specified'}" Because the token doesn't exist in this scenario. How can I correctly make this redirect and work if the token doesn't exist at all?

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

const UserContext = createContext({});

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState();
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    
    function checkAuth() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
            if (localStorage.getItem("access_token") === '') {
            navigate('/auth');
            return false;
            }
            const authData = jwt_decode(token);
            setFirstName(authData.firstname);
            setLastName(authData.lastName);
            setEmail(authData.email);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        checkAuth
        },[checkAuth])

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ 
            firstName, setFirstName, 
            lastName, setLastName,
            email,setEmail
            }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default UserContext;
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` will either return the token or null, so you'll want to check for null instead of an empty string.

```if (!token) { ... }```

Comment: I had tried that previously before posting this and it results int he same error.

Comment: first check your function is calling or not because in your useeffect code you have not add parenthesis after checkAuth function and then after check as  if (token) {...}